# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date>'

Tags: react-datepicker

After I have checked other answers, here is the one that completely works for me:

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date|null>(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date: Date | null) => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```

Comment: Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.